# Two Consecutive Numbers $\sqrt {9n+1} , \sqrt {11n+4} \in\Bbb{N}$

Tags: calculus

Two Consecutive Numbers $\sqrt{9n+1} , \sqrt{11n+4} \in \Bbb{N} $, Find All The Solutions.

Comment: Can you please write the squares in a better way? Is the square only over $11n$ or is it $\sqrt{11n+4}$?

Comment: Presumably it's $\sqrt{9n+1}$ and $\sqrt{11n+4}$.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align*}
\sqrt{9n+1}+1&=\sqrt{11n+4}\\
9n+1+2\sqrt{9n+1}+1&=11n+4\\
\sqrt{9n+1}&=n+1\\
9n+1&=n^2+2n+1\\
7n&=n^2
\end{align*}

$n=0$ or $7$.

Answer (score 1):

We have 
$$\sqrt {11n+4}=\sqrt {9n+1} +1$$
$$\implies $$

$$11n+4=9n+1+2\sqrt {9n+1} +1$$
$$\implies $$

$$n^2+2n+1=9n+1$$
$$\implies $$
$$n (n-7)=0$$
$$\implies $$
$n=0$ which gives $1,2$

or

$n=7$ which gives $8,9$.